# Иногда дублируется надпись "... - новый участник" при написании комментария

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, комментарии, новые-участники

Иногда дублируется надпись "*SomeUser* - новый участник. ..." при написании комментария:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я перезагрузил страницу и ещё раз нажал "Добавить комментарий", такого уже не было.

Что это было?

Comment: У меня тоже иногда такое бывает. При перезагрузке всегда пропадает. То есть исправлять смысла особого нет.

Comment: Есть [репорт на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392049/339911)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка исправлена! С версии 2024.1.9.3159 подобное поведение не должно наблюдаться. [Ответ сотрудника StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427707/17799125):

> This has been fixed in revision 2024.1.9.3159. When closing the dialog, we were making the template (the top one) visible. This way, when showing a form next time we were showing the notification twice...

Что, переводится как-то так:

> Это стало исправлено в ревизии 2024.1.9.3159. При закрытии диалогового окна, мы делаем шаблон (верхний) видимым. Таким образом, при отображении формы в следующий раз, мы показываем уведомление дважды

Если вы сможете перевести этот текст на понятный человеку, а не только сотрудникам, буду благодарен. В любом случае, ошибка исправлена, и всё работает как надо.